# pause a reversed countdown timer in java for android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm making a timer which has a button I can control either pick the count-up mode or countdown mode. The count down mode is working perfectly, start, pause, reset. The count-up timer is made by reversing the countdown timer in Android studio. the problem is I can't pause the count-up timer and resume from where it stops. 
What's the proper way to do that? I know it could be done by chronometer for count-up mode, but I'm trying to make a customized timer widget that as I mentioned before, a button could be pressed to let the user decide which mode he wants. So if possible, I don't want to use another widget in my current set up.

```
public void startBuiltInTimer(int millisecondCountingInterval) {

    if (getTimeInMillis() > 0) { //getTimeInMillis will read the time value in the current Timer widget, which is a textView
        builtInTimerIsCounting = true; //set the timer is running flag
        showAsCounting(true);
        if (getTimerCountUpOrDown() == TIMER_COUNT_DOWN) { //countdown mode
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(getTimeInMillis(), millisecondCountingInterval) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    setTime(millisUntilFinished);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    setTime(0);
                    builtInTimerIsCounting = false;
                    showAsCounting(false);
                    }

                }
            }.start();
        } else if (getTimerCountUpOrDown() == TIMER_COUNT_UP) { //count up mode
            long tempTimeInMillis = getTimeInMillis() + lastTimeMillisUntilFinished; //trying to save the last time value in millis and keep the total time value as user defined.
            setTime(0); //set initial value of the textView to show the count-up timer start from zero, initially.
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(tempTimeInMillis, millisecondCountingInterval) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    long temp = tempTimeInMillis - millisUntilFinished;
                    setTime(temp); //reverse the countdown to count-up
                    lastTimeMillisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;//keep the millisUntilFinished for next start. 
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    setTime(tempTimeInMillis);
                    builtInTimerIsCounting = false;
                    showAsCounting(false);
                    }

                }
            }.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:
I end up to use SystemClock to keep tracking and record the count up timer. Here is the code.

```
else if (getTimerCountUpOrDown() == TIMER_COUNT_UP) {
        startCountUpTimer(millisecondCountingInterval);
}

public void startCountUpTimer(int millisecInterval) {
    if (!countUpTimerIsRunning) {
        handler = new Handler();
        myRunnable = new MyRunnable(millisecInterval);    //MyRunnable can pass a variable thru to let handler have more flexibility with postDelay method. You can still use regular Runnable with hard coded time interval in millisec.
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();    //use startTime to mark the time when the count up timer start ticking
        handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, millisecInterval);
        countUpTimerIsRunning = true;
    }

}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int interval;

    public MyRunnable(int t) {
        this.interval = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        millisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;    //this is the time value measured by the count up timer
        updateTime = timeBuff + millisecondTime;   
        setTime(updateTime);
        if (updateTime <= countUpMode_Threshold) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
        } else {
            setTime(countUpMode_Threshold);
            handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
            builtInTimerIsCounting = false;
            showAsCounting(false);
            if (onBuiltInTimerStatusChangeListener != null) {
                onBuiltInTimerStatusChangeListener.onStatusChange(OnBuiltInTimerStatusChangeListener.STATUS_FINISHED);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void pauseCountUpTimer() {
    timeBuff += millisecondTime;
    handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    countUpTimerIsRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Comment: @RichardDapice Sorry about the delay. No. I end up use the systemClock to do the count up timer. It works for me. I update the post and close it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @apolloneo I see you used SystemClock.uptimeClock(), it depends how you will run your code, but remember it will not include time spent in deep sleep. SystemClock.elapsedRealTime() may be better choice in some cases.

Comment: @3mpty what is the deep sleep, for example, let's say I'm using a tablet, does it mean the tablet is been put into sleep mode or screen lock mode? what is the benefit of using elapsedRealTime(), keep the timer run even in the sleep mode? Not very sure about it, but I appreciate your mention that.

Comment: @apolloneo according to documentation:
#uptimeMilis is counted in miliseconds since the system was booted, but this clock stops when the system enters deep sleep (CPU off, display dark, device is waiting for external input), prolly when device is dozing. #elaspedRealtime ticks even when device is sleeping.

So  it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you should keep track of the pause time manually and start timer from that time again. Or you can try using the utility at [this link](https://gist.github.com/bverc/1492672) It has the functionality you are looking for.
Pretty helpful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
private CountDownTimer timer;
private long COUNT_DOWN = -1;
private long COUNT_UP = 1;


public void startBuiltInTimer(boolean isDown) {
    if (isdown) {
       launchTimer(COUNT_DOWN);
    } else {
       launchTimer(COUNT_UP);
    }
}

public void launchTimer(long interval) {
    builtInTimerIsCounting = true; //set the timer is running flag
    showAsCounting(true);

    timer = new CountDownTimer(getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(interval) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long time) {
         setCountdownText(time.intValue());
         setTimeInMillis(time);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        setCountdownText(time.intValue());
        builtInTimerIsCounting = false;
        showAsCounting(false);
   }
}.start();

public void stopTimer() {
    timer.cancel();
}

...
```